# Android java - azure-storage-blob - blobClient.getProperties().getLastModified() - Wrong number of arguments; expected 1, got 0

Tags: java, android, methods, arguments, azure-blob-storage

When I try to get the last modified date of a Blobclient using the azure blob storage SDK for java, I get the "Wrong number of arguments" error, saying the expected number is 1, even though the documentation says it takes no arguments and that `.getProperties` only has optional arguments.

```
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connection)
                .buildClient()
                .getBlobContainerClient(containerName);


        String sasToken = createContainerSasToken(containerClient);

        BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(endPoint)
                .sasToken(sasToken)
                .buildClient();

        try {

            OffsetDateTime lastModified = blobClient.getProperties().getCreationTime();

            Log.i("Azure storage", "Last modified: " + lastModified);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Azure storage", "Azure storage error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

The log shows this error: "Azure storage error: Wrong number of arguments; expected 1, got 0"

I have tested to check that the blobClient is found, by logging the name of it and it is found so that is not the problem. I am also using the latest azure blob storage com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.25.2.

I have also tried `.getCreationTime()` which throws the same error, so the problem might be with the `.getProperties` method.

EDIT --------------------------------------------------------------------

I have learned a bit more about the azure storage now and found that the .listBlobs for loop never returns anything or exits.

I can succesfully download a blob client item, but if i try to get the last modified parameter of that blob client i get an error: "Wrong number of arguments; expected 1, got 0".

Here is the complete code:

```
package com.example.azureblobstoragepropertiestest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobItem;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String connectStr = "XXXXX";
    private static final String containerName = "XXXXX";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectStr)
                .buildClient()
                .getBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        try {
            String downloadFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath();

            BlobClient blobClientDownload = containerClient.getBlobClient("blobtest.txt");

            String filePath = downloadFolder + "/" + blobClientDownload.getBlobName();

            blobClientDownload.downloadToFile(filePath, true);
            System.out.println("Azure blob file downloaded successfully!");

            String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println("File Content:\n" + fileContent);

            try {
                OffsetDateTime lastModifiedDownload = blobClientDownload.getProperties().getLastModified();
                System.out.println("Last modified date downloaded blob: " + lastModifiedDownload);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Get last modified of downloaded blob error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            System.out.println("Blobs in the container:");
                for (BlobItem blobItem : containerClient.listBlobs()) {
                    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobItem.getName());
                    OffsetDateTime lastModified = blobClient.getProperties().getLastModified();
                    System.out.println("Blob: " + blobItem.getName() + ", Last modified: " + lastModified);
                }
            System.out.println("No more blobs in the container");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Azure storage error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

here is the output log

```
2024-03-04 13:26:34.738 19528-19528 System.err              com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  W  SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2024-03-04 13:26:34.738 19528-19528 System.err              com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  W  SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2024-03-04 13:26:34.738 19528-19528 System.err              com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  W  SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2024-03-04 13:26:34.752 19528-19528 epropertiestest         com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  W  Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V (max-target-o, reflection, denied)
2024-03-04 13:26:34.865 19528-19528 epropertiestest         com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/VM;->maxDirectMemory()J (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2024-03-04 13:26:34.867 19528-19528 PlatformDependent       com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  I  Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be preferred to avoid potential system instability.
2024-03-04 13:26:34.968 19528-19528 epropertiestest         com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  W  type=1400 audit(0.0:3344): avc: denied { read } for name="somaxconn" dev="proc" ino=195365 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c194,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.example.azureblobstoragepropertiestest
2024-03-04 13:26:34.989 19528-19528 epropertiestest         com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  E  No implementation found for int io.netty.internal.tcnative.Library.aprMajorVersion() (tried Java_io_netty_internal_tcnative_Library_aprMajorVersion and Java_io_netty_internal_tcnative_Library_aprMajorVersion__)
2024-03-04 13:26:35.011 19528-19528 epropertiestest         com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  E  No implementation found for int io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.offsetofEpollData() (tried Java_io_netty_channel_epoll_Native_offsetofEpollData and Java_io_netty_channel_epoll_Native_offsetofEpollData__)
2024-03-04 13:26:35.015 19528-19528 epropertiestest         com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  E  No implementation found for int io.netty.channel.kqueue.Native.sizeofKEvent() (tried Java_io_netty_channel_kqueue_Native_sizeofKEvent and Java_io_netty_channel_kqueue_Native_sizeofKEvent__)
2024-03-04 13:26:35.022 19528-19528 epropertiestest         com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  W  Accessing hidden field Lsun/nio/ch/SelectorImpl;->selectedKeys:Ljava/util/Set; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2024-03-04 13:26:35.022 19528-19528 epropertiestest         com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  W  Accessing hidden field Lsun/nio/ch/SelectorImpl;->publicSelectedKeys:Ljava/util/Set; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2024-03-04 13:26:35.029 19528-19528 TrafficStats            com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  D  tagSocket(130) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2024-03-04 13:26:35.031 19528-19528 Compatibil...geReporter com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  D  Compat change id reported: 170188668; UID 10194; state: ENABLED
2024-03-04 13:26:35.033 19528-19528 MacAddressUtil          com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  W  Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: 6b:dd:5f:a8:87:5b:5e:0c
2024-03-04 13:26:35.346 19528-19528 System.out              com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  I  Azure blob file downloaded successfully!
2024-03-04 13:26:35.352 19528-19528 System.out              com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  I  File Content:
2024-03-04 13:26:35.352 19528-19528 System.out              com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  I  This is a test blob uploaded to azure storage, to check if they can be downloaded.
2024-03-04 13:26:35.393 19528-19528 System.err              com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  W  Get last modified of downloaded blob error: Wrong number of arguments; expected 1, got 0
2024-03-04 13:26:35.393 19528-19528 System.out              com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  I  Blobs in the container:
2024-03-04 13:26:54.920 19528-19538 epropertiestest         com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 160645(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 16(336KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 9573KB/18MB, paused 197us,39us total 114.732ms
2024-03-04 13:26:54.923 19528-19540 System                  com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  W  A resource failed to call close. 
2024-03-04 13:27:38.643 19528-19542 epropertiestest         com...zureblobstoragepropertiestest  I  Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 805(67KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 9574KB/18MB, paused 61us,40us total 70.543ms
```

here is a snippet from the azure portal, showing that the calls do go through. [Azure activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVYn1.png).

Answer (score 0):

> To get the last modified date of a Blobclient using the Azure blob storage SDK for java

You can use the below code to get the last modified date and time in the container using Azure Java SDK.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobItem;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectStr = "xxxxx";
        String containerName = "xxxx";

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectStr)
                .buildClient()
                .getBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        try {
            for (BlobItem blobItem : containerClient.listBlobs()) {
                BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobItem.getName());
                OffsetDateTime lastModified = blobClient.getProperties().getLastModified();
                System.out.println("Blob: " + blobItem.getName() + ", Last modified: " + lastModified);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Azure storage error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The above code uses the Azure Storage Blob Java SDK to connect to a storage account using a connection string and retrieve a container client. It then lists all the blobs in the container along with their **`last modified date`**. If any error occurs during the process, it prints an error message.

**Output:**

```
Blob: currency.csv, Last modified: 2024-01-19T11:18:59Z
Blob: demo.mp4, Last modified: 2024-02-21T05:16:48Z
Blob: sample-file-sd.mp4, Last modified: 2024-02-21T06:55:34Z
```

[image]

**Dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.25.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Reference:**
[Quickstart: Azure Blob Storage library - Java | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli)

Comment: Your solution didn't give any output. I tried adding a System.out at the start of the try block, which does give an output. It seems like the container is empty, though there are 4 blob blocks in it. The container access level is private, but I have added the SASToken. I tried to just access some basic information of the container "containerClient.getBlobContainerName()" and "containerClient.getBlobContainerUrl()", that throws the same exception: "Wrong number of arguments; expected 1, got 0". I can download a blob from the client but i cannot get the meta information.

Comment: With connection string you can able to fetch the container if it is private also as you mentioned in question.

Comment: Please add the code now you have tried in question.

Comment: I get the same result with the connection string as with the SASToken. I couldn't figure out how to add code to a comment, but I have edited the question.

Comment: I just ran the code again and studied the output, i get this line right after the "blobs in the container:" type=1400 audit(0.0:1003): avc: denied { read } for name="somaxconn" dev="proc" ino=92873 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c194,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.example.azureblobstoragepropertiestest but why isn't the app trusted when it has the connectionstring with the key/SASToken

Comment: Add the code in question

Comment: You need to use either one of them for authentication.

Comment: You can use `BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectStr)
                .buildClient()
                .getBlobContainerClient(containerName);` in your code.

Comment: I have now studied a bit more about the azure storage. I have updated my question with the revised description of issues and updated code as well as the logcat. I am sorry for the inconvenience.